# Jquery Count LI and IF odd do something

Tags: jquery, if-statement, html-lists

If a UL has odd number of LI records, I want to add a BREAK tag (`<br />`) after the first LI.

This is the result if the number of LI is EVEN:

```
  <ul id="cat">
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
  </ul>
```

This is the result if the number of LI is ODD:

```
  <ul id="cat">
    <li><a href=""></a></li><br />
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
  </ul>
```

My jQuery snippet:

```
$("#cat").each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    if (elem.children("li").length % 2 != 0) {
        elem.prepend("<br />");
    }
});
```

It just results in

```
      <ul id="cat">
<br />
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is you prepend to the UL. Which will add a 
 before all LI's. If you get the first LI and you do `after()` the BR is added after the LI. Also this is not valid HTML. So please use CSS for this.

If you still want to use Javascript this way:

```
$("#cat").each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    if (elem.children("li").length % 2 != 0) {
        elem.children("li").first().after("<br />");
    }
});
```

But why a BR after a LI? Can't you just solve this with CSS?

```
li {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I never knew <BR /> was not valid xHTML. Thanks. Everyone + you marked up and you answer marked.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid it _is_ valid xHTML, but _only_ if you put it in the right place.  A list can only contain list items, so it's not valid there.

Comment: <li>content <br /></li> or <li>content</li> <br />

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#cat").each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    if (elem.children("li").length % 2 != 0) {
        elem.find(">:first-child").prepend("<br />");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$("#cat").each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    if (elem.children("li").length % 2 != 0) {
        elem.find("li:first").append("<br />");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use children("li:first") and .after() to insert 
 after the first LI.

```
$("#cat").each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    if (elem.children("li").length % 2 != 0) {
        elem.children("li:first").after("<br />");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't insert anything other than `<li>` tags inside your list - it's not valid HTML.

I would go for:

```
elem.children().first().css('display', 'block');
```

However the exact CSS depends on exactly it is you're trying to achieve visually.

Answer (score 1):

use css to get your output instead

if you set this to the first il you will get the same effect

```
clear:both;
display:block;
```